# How to extract date from a string of format dd-mmm-yyyy in js

Tags: javascript

How can I extract date from a string where date format is `dd-mmm-yyyy` (example `01-dec-2020`) in `Javascript` using regular expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Also see https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: ok,will do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use this regex: `\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}`

```js
let str = 'something 01-dec-2020 something';

let result = str.match(/\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}/);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: let me know how you are using it

Comment: const dateRegEx = /(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g;
 const result = await k.body.match(dateRegEx);
this is the code iam using to match date format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: will check the method.

Comment: please see my code snippet above. It might help you.

Comment: could you also tell me how to get more knowledge in regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spell out the exact months, here is the regex I came up with:

```
var dates = text.match(/\d{2}-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-\d{4}/gi);
```

Fiddle, for example, which outputs to the console:

https://jsfiddle.net/sok0u9mb/